# Unit testing text output (stdout.write/print) in Dart

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I am looking for a way in the Dart programming language to redirect the 
output from stdout, into a "Something", that I can call .toString() on, and get
anything printed on stdout as String. This is useful for unit tests.

Currently I wrap stdout in my Display class, and store the text for one call and verify that stdout's write is
used. See also my side note below, how it can be done in Java.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

class Display {
  IOSink output;
  String lastTextPrinted;

  Display(IOSink output) {
    this.output = output;
  }

  void myPrint(String text) {
    lastTextPrinted = text;
    output.write(text);
  }
}

main() {
  test('prints hello world', () {
    Display display = new Display(stdout);
    display.myPrint("Hello world!");
    expect("Hello world!", display.lastTextPrinted);
  });

  test('myPrint calls ioSinks write', () {
    MockIOSink ioSink = new MockIOSink();
    Display display = Display(ioSink);
    display.myPrint("Hello world!");

    verify(ioSink.write("Hello world!"));
  });
}

class MockIOSink extends Mock implements IOSink {}
```

Sidenote: In Java with JUnit 4 I used something similar to this:

There System.out is a PrintStream and I can assign my own Stream to it, for instance ByteArrayOutPutStream.
The latter has a .toString method I can call to verify its content against.

```
@Test
public void testMyMessageToDisplay() throws Exception
{
 ByteArrayOutputStream canvas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 System.setOut(new PrintStream(canvas);

 new Display().displayMyMessage("Hello world!");

 Assert.assertEquals("Hello World!", canvas.toString("UTF-8"));
}

public static class Display {
    public void displayMyMessage(String myMessage) {
        System.out.println(myMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the second test is sufficient and we can remove the `lastTextPrinted` as it is added only for testing purpose.

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian ty for this hint. It makes sense. I forgot, that the mocking verifies the equality of the arguments too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test_process – it gives a lot of nice methods for verifying the output of a process

See the example in the readme:

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:test_process/test_process.dart';

void main() {
  test("pub get gets dependencies", () async {
    var process = await TestProcess.start("pub", ["get"]);

    // Each stream matcher will consume as many lines as it matches from a
    // StreamQueue, and no more, so it's safe to use them in sequence.
    await expectLater(process.stdout, emits("Resolving dependencies..."));

    // The emitsThrough matcher matches and consumes any number of lines, as
    // long as they end with one matching the argument.
    await expectLater(process.stdout, emitsThrough("Got dependencies!"));

    await process.shouldExit(0);
  });
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20421402)

Comment: @Minsky – does this help?

Comment: @KevinMoore Looks great, I will try it, when I am near my computer in two weeks. Thank you!

Comment: It took me more time, because I use a Flutter environment and the test_process plugin was not compatible until some weeks ago. Nevertheless, I didn't get it to work. I don't have an idea how to hook my Display class's output into the TestProcess. I even are not sure what is my parameter for the TestProcess.start call. Using "cmd" for instance gives me just the output of cmd.exe on Windows and I even cannot get "expectLater" to parse its default output. So any further ideas are welcome.